# jpg loaded with python keras is different from jpg loaded in javascript

Tags: javascript, numpy, keras, python-imaging-library, tensorflow.js

I am loading jpg image in python on the server. Then I am loading the same jpg image with javascript on the client. Finally, I am trying to compare it with the python output. But loaded data are different so images do not match. Where do I have a mistake?

Python code

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array    
filename = './rcl.jpg'
original = load_img(filename)
numpy_image = img_to_array(original)
print(numpy_image)
```

JS code

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
photo() {
    var can = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    img.src = './rcl.jpg';

    var tensor = tf.fromPixels(can).toFloat();
    tensor.print()

}
```

Comment: Why do you have to draw the image on the canvas before rendering it as a tensor ?

Comment: I tried to add exact image size, but it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are drawing the image on a canvas before rendering the canvas as a tensor. Drawing on a canvas can alter the shape of the initial image. For instance, unless specified otherwise - which is the case with your code - the canvas is created with a width of 300 px and a height of 150 px. Therefore the resulting shape of the tensor will be more or less something like the following [150, 300, 3].

**1- Using Canvas**

Canvas are suited to resize an image as one can draw on the canvas all or part of the initial image. In that case, one needs to resize the canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.create('canvas')
// canvas has initial width: 300px and height: 150px
canvas.width = image.width
canvas.height = image.heigth
// canvas is set to redraw the initial image
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0) // to draw the entire image
```

One word of caution though: all the above piece should be executed after the image has finished loading using the event handler `onload` as the following

```js
    const im = new Image()
    im.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    im.src = 'url'
    // document.body.appendChild(im) (optional if the image should be displayed)
    im.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.create('canvas')
      canvas.width = image.width
      canvas.height = image.heigth
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
    }
```

or using async/await

```js
function load(url){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const im = new Image()
        im.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
        im.src = 'url'
        im.onload = () => {
          resolve(im)
        }
   })
}

// use the load function inside an async function   

(async() => {
     const image = await load(url)
     const canvas = document.create('canvas')
     canvas.width = image.width
     canvas.height = image.heigth
     const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
     ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0) 
   })()
```

**2- Using fromPixel on the image directly**

If the image is not to be resized, you can directly render the image as a tensor using `fromPixel` on the image itself

Comment: The reason why I am using canvas is that finally, I am going to use the stream from webcam to get a feature vector. Using image now is just for testing purposes... Nevertheles, I will try it with raw image and let you know